# Angular Material Paginator

Tags: angular

I'm gonna be very specific with my question, hoping for an equally specific answer.

I've combed online, and the [Angular docs on the subject](https://material.angular.io/components/paginator) is as vague for real life cases as asking you to pick a needle from the ocean. Ooh Angular docs...

What I have done so far

```xml
  <mat-paginator (page)="pageEvent = $event" #paginator [length]="pageLength" [pageSize]="pageSize" [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizeOptions">
  </mat-paginator>
```

And this in my component

```typescript
  pageLength: number;
  pageSize: 5;
  pageSizeOptions = [5, 10, 25, 100];
```

and then I update the `pageLength` when the endpoint response is in like so:

```typescript
  loadRequests() {
    this.busy = true;
    this.request_service.get_requests()
      .subscribe((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        this.requests = res['requests'];
        this.pageLength = this.requests.length; // let's assume length = 1000
      });
  }
```

The above renders renders the UI for the pagination nicely in the browser

The endpoint being consumed via `.get_requests()`, for the sake of simplicity, returns only 1000 fixed items.

Now, this is how I'm rendering my list at the moment:

```xml
<mat-card *ngFor="let request of requests">
  <mat-card-title> {{ request.title }}</mat-card-title>
</mat-card>
```

So with the above preamble, what steps are my left to complete to get pagination to work with this condition in mind:

- The pagination doesn't keep going to endpoint to pull each list of items for each pageIndex.
- After receiving the 1000 items at first hit from the endpoint, then pagination chunks this length of items up **locally** on the client side. No more API calls.

Comment: Everytime the paginator raises an event you need to hit the  endpoint yourself

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Let's assume you've loaded the response data (Array) in requests .

You can probably create a method that returns a set of data from the requests property using the splice method.

Therefore, on the API subscribe results, it can be handled like this for the first time load:

```typescript
this.request_service.get_requests()
  .subscribe((res) => {
    this.pageLength = res['requests'].length;
    this.splicedData = res['requests'].slice(((0 + 1) - 1) * this.pageSize).slice(0, this.pageSize);
  });
```

where `pageSize`, has been defined in earlier on to a default value.

Then, anytime the user changes the `mat-paginator` component in the template, the `pageChangeEvent` is run. Template looks like this:

```xml
  <mat-paginator (page)="pageChangeEvent($event)" [length]="pageLength" [pageSize]="pageSize" [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizeOptions">
  </mat-paginator>
```

Then its corresponding component method is this.

```typescript
 pageChangeEvent(event) {
    const offset = ((event.pageIndex + 1) - 1) * event.pageSize;
    this.splicedData = this.requests.slice(offset).slice(0, event.pageSize);
  }
```

Finally, your `*ngFor` can use the `splicedData` array to populate itself.

```xml
<mat-card *ngFor="let request of splicedData">
    <mat-card-title> {{ request.title }}</mat-card-title>
</mat-card>
```

Comment: Will give it a try. However it already makes sense from just looking at it. Thankfully an answer that doesn't make use of matTable and its related accoutrements.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Marked as correct after making a few changes. You used no matTable stuff. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: I don't get this particular point though `((0 + 1) - 1) * this.pageSize`, wont this allways be equal to 1 since `((0 + 1) - 1` is always 0?

Answer (score 4):

You could use the `mat-table`, it integrates very well with the `mat-paginator`. Hiding the header and changing the style to make it look the way you want.

The component :

```typescript
displayedColumns: string[] = ['requests'];
dataSource: MatTableDataSource<{request: number}>;
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
@ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

constructor() {
 this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(values);
}

ngOnInit() {
 this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
 this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
}
```

The template :

```xml
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>

 <!-- Requests Column -->
   <ng-container matColumnDef="requests">
     <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header/>
     <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.request.title}} </td>
   </ng-container>

   <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"/>
   <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;">
   </tr>
</table>

<mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]"/>
```

[Here is a running example.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-51736551)

Comment: Thanks. I guess i should include this little part in the original post because I'm not really interested in solutions using the matTable and or its related tags etc. I wanted raw, no extra strings attached, matPaginator used alone. I mentioned that in the bounty text though.

Answer (score 0):

I used GitHub API for this example, you need to wait for the event on the paginator and then do the HTTP call to fetch the data

[Angular Material Paginator example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1dep1k)

Comment: thanks for the example. I like the current implementation, and its use case exists for live loading data. In my use case (I've updated the question) the endpoint only returns, say, 1000 items. No back and forth API calls. The paginator thus handles the chunking locally on the client on the 1000 received items. Sorry I didn't make that point clearer earlier. At the moment, you solution works really well for live at-each-page endpoint data fetch.

Answer (score 0):

```
<mat-paginator [length]="pagelength"
                  [pageSize]="pageSize"
                  [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizeOptions"
                  [showFirstLastButtons]="true"
                  (page)="goToPage($event)">
    </mat-paginator>




  public goToPage(pageEvent:PageEvent){
// the pageIndex is 0 in Mat-paginator
    this.pagelength = pageEvent.pageIndex+1;
    this.pageSize = pageEvent.pageSize;

    this.loadRequests(
      this.pageLength,
      this.pageSize,

    );
  }
  private _loadRequests(
    page: number,pageSize:number
  ) {
    this.RequestService.getAllRequests(
      page,pageSize
    ).subscribe((response) => {
      this.requests = response.requests;
    this.totalRequests = response.count;
    }, (error) =>
        );
  }
```